# pass argument to previous activity

Tags: android

I would like to pass arguments from an activity B to A where B has been launched by A. Is this possible to do so ?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if when you launch `Activity` B from A, you start it using `startActivityForResult` then you can set a result in `Activity` B then read the value in A.

In A you would need to override `onActivityResult` to get the result value.

In `Activity` B:

```
// do stuff
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Then in A:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    //check result
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To expand a bit on davec's answer:

If you need more data than just RESULT_OK, then you will have to use putExtra() in B and getExtras() in A. You can send primitive data types, e.g for String:

In B:

```
String str1 = "Some Result";
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("myStringData", str1);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

Then to pick it up in A:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (data != null) {
         Bundle b = data.getExtras(); 
         String str = b.getString("myStringData");
      }
   }
}
```

.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) (to be called from A), [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) (to be called from B), and [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) (A's callback that gets called after B exits).